# How to Get Chosen typed value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i need to show searching value from alert when click on 'no_results_text' if it's not available on the list.
i have put  and on click method as 'no_results_text', so i need that typed value in alert

[image]

````
    window.onload = function () {
        $('#secondary_diagnosis').chosen({no_results_text: '<a onclick="add_new_diagnosis()">Save as New </a>'});
    }

    function add_new_diagnosis() {
        alert($('#secondary_diagnosis input').val());
    }```
````

Comment: Can you please provide complete code or relevant code that to input / minimal working example ?

Comment: chosen is like this `<select name="test_chosen" id="test_chosen"
                            class="form-control chosen">
                       <option>1</option>
                       <option>2</option>
                       <option>3</option>
                       <option>4</option>
                    </select>`

Comment: Where is the input ? where you are typing that text for new `diagnosis`

Comment: script  is `<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
        $('#test_chosen').chosen({no_results_text: '<a onclick="add_new()">Save as New </a>'});
    }

    function add_new() {
        alert($('#test_chosen input').val());
    }
</script>`

Comment: input default coming from chosen

Comment: i need that value get to show in alert

Comment: You mean you want to see the value of the selected option from the `dropdown (Select)`?

Comment: There is no function in jQuery called `.chosen`

Comment: no. i need show alert if typed value not in that chosen selection. eg: select options only have 1 to 10 options. but when type 20 on chosen need to show alert '20 not in list'. likw that

Comment: .chosen is bootstrap class

Comment: Where do you typed the value ? Where is the input ?

Comment: i have show it in picture on question. like [link](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = function () {
        $('#secondary_diagnosis').chosen({no_results_text: '<a onclick="add_new_diagnosis()">Save as New </a>'});
    }
```

in the `window.onload` you can set the `onclick` funtion to the default value to the chosen. after click it, you can get that typed value like this.

```
var new_value = $('.chosen-results .no-results span').text();
aleart('typed value is : '+ new_value);
```